# "Check with someone to see if they are willing to..." or "check with someone to see if they will be willing to..."?

Tags: present-simple, future-constructions

Could you tell me if I have to use the present simple or the future simple in the context below?

> First I need to check with the driver to see if they **are** willing to sell the car for that money.
>
> First I need to check with the driver to see if they **will be** willing to sell the car for that money.

To me both seem correct, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Did you mean 'driver'? In this case, the present tense refers to the time when you check with them; you don't need to use the future tense on the grounds that the conversation hasn't yet taken place. The first sentence is the correct one.

Comment: Both versions are fine, but idiomatically I think most native speakers would probably use ***would be*** rather than ***are*** or ***will be*** in such contexts.

Comment: Actually - I've just checked Google Books, and can confirm that there are more hits for ***"see if they would be willing"*** than for the same with either ***are*** or ***will be*** (but ***are*** is only *slightly* less common than ***will be***).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any difference between the two sentences is the same difference as normal between *present simple* and *future simple*: with "will", it suggests the driver may make their decision farther in the future than when I check with them, or that the decision might be conditional upon something else, like:

> "*... if they will be willing to sell the car for that money **if I pay cash**.*"